# How to navigate from recycler view to an other activity and pass parameters

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

i implemented a recycler view and it works fine , but when i wanted to handle the click of the button i user an intent inside the recycler view fragment , but it seems like i can not use intents here to pass parameters to an activity and navigate to it

//my recyler view adapter

```
package com.example.miniprojetandroid.adapters;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.R;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.models.Bike;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.ui.activities.BikeDetails;
import com.example.miniprojetandroid.ui.activities.MainActivity;


public class BikesAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<Bike> bikes;
    private Context mContext;

public BikesAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Bike> bikes) {
        this.mContext = mContext ;
        this.bikes = bikes;
        }

@NonNull
@Override
public BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View mItemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.bike_list_item, parent, false);

        return new BikesViewHolder(mItemView, this);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BikesAdapter.BikesViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Bike singleItem = bikes.get(position);

        holder.BikeName.setText(singleItem.getModel());

        holder.BikeImage.setBackgroundResource(singleItem.getImage());
        holder.bikeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, BikeDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("bike_id", singleItem.getId());
                intent.putExtra("model", singleItem.getModel());
                intent.putExtra("type", singleItem.getType());
                intent.putExtra("price",   singleItem.getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("image",  singleItem.getImage());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        holder.BikeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,singleItem.getModel(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
        }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return bikes.size();
        }

public class BikesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final TextView BikeName;
    public final ImageView BikeImage;
    public final Button bikeView;
    final BikesAdapter mAdapter;

    public BikesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, BikesAdapter mAdapter) {
        super(itemView);
        this.BikeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikeName);
        this.BikeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikeImage);
        this.bikeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_view);
        this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
    }
}



}
```

how to navigate to BikeDetails with intent parameters after the click on bikeView button?
and why the intent can not be recognized here?

the whole problem is in these lines :

```
holder.bikeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, BikeDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("bike_id", singleItem.getId());
                intent.putExtra("model", singleItem.getModel());
                intent.putExtra("type", singleItem.getType());
                intent.putExtra("price",   singleItem.getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("image",  singleItem.getImage());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a callback to pass an event into an activity that uses your RecyclerView.
Take a look at this article https://medium.com/pongploydev/how-to-use-listener-interface-callback-in-activity-fragment-ff3733c80ddd for more info.

Comment: what about if i delete the DetailsActivity and replace it by a fragment which will show the details of the recycler view selected item but i am wondering how a fragment pass an object Bike to another fragment

Answer (score 1):

When you create an intent to start an activity, the first parameter should be a Context and the `startActivity` method belongs to the Context class, not RecyclerView.Adapter. Also, the `finish` method belongs to Activity so calling it from your adapter won't work either.

The example below should give you a rough idea of how you can make it work.

```
holder.bikeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = v.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, BikeDetails.class);
        // extras
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Side note: your Bike object can be an implementation of Parcelable, that way you don't need to pass every single field of it as an extra on your intent, you can simply pass the whole thing, like this:

```
// Passing data
intent.putExtra("bike", singleItem);

// Fetching data
Bike bike = getIntent().getParcelableExtra<Bike>("bike");
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("bike", singleItem);  did not work , it appears that the line is in red , error in syntax

Comment: It's probably because your Bike class isn't an implementation of Parcelable yet. But that's not quite within the scope of this question, it was just a tip

Comment: i did it , the data come null from recycler view fragment to BikeDetails activity

Comment: Most simplest solution on the Internet. Thank you!